# Trig identity question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Show that $\sin(2nx)=\sin((2n+1)x)\cos(x)-\cos((2n+1)x)\sin(x)$.

I have the mark scheme in front of me, but it doesn't make sense to me...

$$\sin((2n+1)x)\cos(x)-\cos((2n+1)x)\sin(x)=\sin((2n+1)x)-x=\sin(2nx)$$

Initially, I would think that it would be a double angle identity so $\sin2\theta=2\sin\theta \cos\theta$, where $\theta$ here is $nx$ but that doesn't seem to be it. How does the cosine disappear from the solution in the mark scheme? If someone could explain every step, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: $(2n+1)x = 2nx + x$

Answer (score 4):

Using [angle sum and difference identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities): $\sin (A-B) = \sin A \cos B - \cos A \sin B$, the RHS can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
\sin (2n+1)x \cos x - \cos (2n+1)x \sin x&=\sin((2n+1)x-x)\\
&=\sin(2nx+x-x)\\
&=\sin 2nx.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, RHS = LHS.

Answer (score 3):

Use the identity $$
\sin (a-b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b
$$
Where $a$ = $(2n+1)x$ and $b=x$